What is the number of possible orders for this list of real numbers?
Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be some distinct positive real numbers.
What is the number of orders of the set $S = \{a_1,\ldots,a_n, 1-a_1, \ldots, 1-a_n\}$?
For simplicity, assume that all $2n$ numbers in $S$ are distinct. If we had just arbitrary $2n$ numbers, then there were $(2n)!$ different orders. However, the numbers are related: for any fixed order of $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$, the order of the complementary elements $\{1-a_1,\ldots,1-a_n\}$ is fixed. For example, if $a_1 < \cdots < a_n$, then
$1 - a_n < \cdots < 1-a_1$. So the number of possible orders on $S$ is definitely less than $(2n)!$.
On the other hand, for any fixed order of $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$, there are many different ways to "merge" the numbers $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ with their complements. For example, if $a_1 < a_2$, then we know that $1-a_2 < 1-a_1$, but it is possible that $a_1 < a_2 < 1-a_2 < 1-a_1$, or $a_1 < 1-a_1 < 1- a_2 < 1-a_1$, etc. So the answer is definitely more than $n!$.
Note that not all "merges" of the two sequences are possible. This is because $a_i < 1-a_i$ if and only if $a_i < 0.5$. Therefore, if $a_i < 1-a_i$ and $a_j < a_i$, then $a_j < 1-a_j$ too. So the order $a_1 < 1-a_1 < a_2 < 1-a_2$ is not possible.
How can I count the number of possible orders?

Why are the orders of the complementary elements fixed?

You are going to have to clearly indicate what the rules are for merging the sequences.

The lowest $n/2$ of the $a_i$ and the lowest $n/2$ of the $1-a_i$ may be in any order because they are independent, so that gives another factor of $n\choose n/2$

@QthePlatypus I edited the question to clarify that.

The only constraint (in some sense) is that the arrangement is reflected across $0.5$, so to specify an arrangement, we just need to choose how many of the $a_i$ are larger than $0.5$ and then choose how to interleave those with the reflections of the others.

Why do you assume that, say, the order of $7-3$ and $7-5$ is fixed if you haven’t fixed the order of $3$ and $5$? In fact you’ve said that any of the $2^n$ orders is possible, depending on the $a_i$. So what exactly are you asking?

What do you mean by "the number of orders of the set $S$"? The number of total orders on a finite set $S$ is always $|S|!$, but it seems clear that that's not what you're asking. Another possible way of interpreting your question is "what is the number of total orders of the set $S$ which respect the standard ordering of the real numbers," but the answer to that is always $1$, so that can't be what you're asking, either. Can you try to clarify what you mean?

The intended question is: how many permutations of ${1,\dots,2n}$ can arise from sorting the elements of a tuple of the form $(a_1,\dots,a_n,1-a_1,\dots,1-a_n)$ from smallest to largest?

Here is my best guess for what the intended meaning of the question is. Suppose we have a fixed number $n$, and then we have the opportunity to choose a set of real numbers $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ with the property that if some number $a$ is in the set, then $1 - a$ is not also in the set. We then write a list, in ascending numerical order, of all numbers which are either of the form $a_i$ or of the form $1 - a_i$. We highlight numbers of the form $a_i$ in red and numbers of the form $1 - a_i$ in blue. What is the number of distinct sequences of red and blue highlights that we can achieve?

@TannerSwett the red and blue colorings are not relevant. Instead of coloring the numbers, you write near each number its "label", which can be $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ or $1-a_1,\ldots,1-a_n$. The question is what is the number of distinct sequences of labels that we can achieve?

There are $n!\times 2^n$ possible orders. The $n!$ comes from ordering the $a_i$, and the $2^n$ comes from choosing, for each of the first $n$ positions in the order (corresponding to the values $<0.5$), whether that position is occupied by an $a_i$ or a $1-a_i$.
